# pass parameters pinterest app ios like facebook and twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, parameter-passing, pinterest

I want to pass parameters to pinterest app on IOS like facebook and twitter app to show some page...

"pinterest:// " is working to open app, but I want to open page of some board/people...

any help will be appriciated ..

Answer (score 0):

pinterest does not have a public API, there is now way to do this.

Comment: Sorry it should bene 'not have'